# I need some help on polynomials

Tags: c#, arrays, console, polynomial-math

How would I create a polynomial function using an array? Basically I want to display the polynomial (ex.  x^2 + 3x + 5). Then, I want to show what the highest polynomial degree is. For example, x^2 + 3x + 5 = 2 (highest degree).

Comment: What code are you using to express your polynomials in your program, `Math.Pow()` I imagine since it's C#? Let's see your code...

Comment: Yes, I was think of using Math.Pow() and a loop that will fill the exponent part.

Comment: I have been trying to create the polynomial using an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
// initial highest exponent
int exponent = 0;

// We're assuming [in] is a stream such as istream in C++.
if (char == ^)
{
     in >> char;

     if (char > initial)
     {
          initial = char)
     }
 }
```

We also have to check if the `char` after `x` is a `+`, `-`, or white space. We want to also check for that exponent.

Answer (score 1):

I might recommend doing it like this.

```
        string polynomial = "x^2 + 3x + 5";
        int index = 0,highestdegree = 0;
        foreach (char character in polynomial) {
            if(character == '^')
            {
                index++;
                try{
                    int test;
                    int.TryParse(polynomial[index],out test);
                    if(test >highestdegree)
                        highestdegree = test;
                    index--;
                }
                catch{
                    index--;
                }
            }
            index += 1;
        }
      if(highest degree == 0)
       { 
            highestdegree == 1;
       }
      return highest degree;
```

You would have to turn your polynomial to a string first though.